# How to improve this patternless database schema?

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

Before jumping into the schema and tables, I would like to share what I am trying to achieve first. I am working on sort of a courier application, where I have some `categories` and each category has a pre-defined `price`.

But, determining the price is a bit ugly (absence of symmetry and patterns; at least, I can't seem to find any) . I will give you an example:

Consider the following categories: Document, Heavy Document, Laptop, Carton, Heavy Carton.

1) **Document:** It's for the lighter documents, which are below 0.5kg. The price is 20$, fixed.

*[price stored in the prices table: 20.00]*

> e.g. For an item of 300g, the price will be 20$.

2) **Heavy Document:** This is for the documents that are over 0.5kg. Unlike the Document category, it doesn't have a fixed price! Rather, it has a unit price: 10$ per kg, which will be applied to each kg's except/after 0.5kg.

*[price stored in the prices table: 10.00]*

> e.g. For an item of 2kg, the price will be 35$ (1.5g = 15$ + 0.5 = 20$)

3) **Laptop:** Straightforward, 100$. Nothing special about it, no constraint whatsoever.

*[price stored in the prices table: 100.00]*

> e.g. For an item of 2kg, the price will be 35$ (1.5g = 15$ + 0.5 = 20$)

4) **Carton:** Here comes an interesting one. Until now there was only one dependency: `weight`. But this one has an additional dependency: `dimension`. This is somewhat similar to Document category. For the cartons that are below 3 Cubic Feet(CF), the price is 80$ per CF. The difference between Document and Carton category is that, Document has a fixed price whereas Carton has Unit Price. But wait, there's more. There is an additional constraint: dimension-weight ratio. In this case, it is `7kg per CF`. And if the item's weight crosses the ratio, for each extra kg's 5$ will be charged. It's so confusing, I know. An example might help:

*[price stored in the prices table: 80.00]*

> e.g. For a carton of 80kg and 2CF; the price will be 490$. Here is how:

First calculate the regular charge: 80$*2CF = 160$
Now let's figure out if it crosses **Ratio**: Since, 1 CF = 7kg, hence, 2CF = 14kg. But the item's weight is 80kg, so it *crosses the ratio (14kg)*

Since it crosses the ratio, for all the extra kgs (80-14 = 66kg), each kg will cost 5$: 66*5 = 330$. After adding it with regular charge: 330$+160$ = 490$.

5) **Heavy Carton:** This one is for the cartons having the dimension bigger than 3CF. The difference with Carton is the unit price. Heavy Carton is 60$ per CF.

*[price stored in the prices table: 60.00]*

> e.g. For a carton of 80kg and 5CF; the price will be 525$. Here is how:

First calculate the regular charge: 60$*5CF = 300$
Now let's figure out if it crosses **Ratio**: Since, 1 CF = 7kg, hence, 5CF = 35kg. But the item's weight is 80kg, so it *crosses the ratio (35kg)*

Since it crosses the ratio, for all the extra kgs (80-35 = 45kg), each kg will cost 5$: 45*5 = 225$. After adding it with regular charge: 300$+225$ = 325$.

If you've read this far, I think I have convinced you that the business structure is really complicated. Now let's take a look at my `categories` schema:

```
+-------------------------+---------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                   | Type                            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                      | int(10) unsigned                | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name                    | varchar(191)                    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at              | timestamp                       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at              | timestamp                       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| dim_dependency          | tinyint(1)                      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| weight_dependency       | tinyint(1)                      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| distance_dependency     | tinyint(1)                      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dim_weight_ratio        | varchar(191)                    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| constraint_value        | decimal(8,2)                    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| constraint_on           | enum('weight','dim')            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| size                    | enum('short','regular','large') | YES  |     | regular |                |
| over_ratio_price_per_kg | decimal(8,2)                    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at              | timestamp                       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Also the schema of `prices` table (it's a polymorphic table, hoping to create a `subcategories` table someday):

```
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| amount         | decimal(8,2)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at     | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at     | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| priceable_type | varchar(191)        | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| priceable_id   | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at     | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

How can I improve this structure to keep things as much dynamic and coherent as possible?

Comment: A different opinion here. The question is: *is it possible to use a SQL DB instead of a rule engine?* Yes sometimes, but is it optimal or advisable?. Consider using a rule engine  -- or service (plain code) -- for the rules and use DB just for recording the predicate `User (USR) got price (PRI) for product (PRD) based on rule number (RNO).` You can document rules in a different system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I want to send a `10kg/2.99cf` package, you charge me `240$` (`3*80$`) for a Carton. If I put that package in a slightly bigger box and now want to send it as a `10kg/3.01cf` package, you charge me `180$`(`3*60$`) for a Heavy Carton. In case you round up to the next full `cf`, let's assume I want to send a `80kg/3CF` package; you charge me `535$` (`3*80+59*5`). If I put the same package in a bigger box with `80kg/4CF`, you charge me just `500$` (`4*60+52*5`).

That is indeed a good sign *"that the business structure is really complicated"* (even if those might be just examples values, it shows the potential to overcomplicate things).

Anyway, I would probably encode your conditions in a table like that:

```
category |max_kg|max_cf|is_laptop|price|p_p_kg|p_p_cf|off_kg|off_cf|off_rat
---------+------+------+---------+-----+------+------+------+------+--------
Document | 0.5  | null |    0    |  20 |   0  |   0  |  0   |  0   |  0     
Heavy Doc|  2   | null |    0    |  20 |  10  |   0  | 0.5  |  0   |  0   
Laptop   | null | null |    1    | 100 |   0  |   0  |  0   |  0   |  0  
Carton   | null |   3  |    0    |   0 |   5  |  80  |  0   |  0   |  7  
Heavy C. | null | null |    0    | 180 |   5  |  60  |  0   |  3   |  7
```

There are probably some size constraints for documents too (can I e.g. send my `0.0kg/100cf` helium-filled ballon as a document?), but you haven't specified them; listing the conditions that way should make it obvious where you have unspecific conditions though.

`off_*` specifies offsets, e.g. the amount already included in `price`; `p_p_kg` is the *price per kg* for the remaining weight (reduced by the offset), analogous for `p_p_cf`. So a heavy carton with `80kg/4CF` would be calculated as

```
price    -- 180
+ p_p_kg * greatest(kg - off_rat * cf - off_kg, 0)  -- 5 * (80-7*4-0) 
+ p_p_cf * greatest(cf - off_cf, 0) -- 60 * (4 - 3)
```

so, as expected, `180 + 5 * 52 + 60 = 500`.

The user will not come to your shop and say *"I want to send this as a Heavy Carton"*. He will say: *"What does it cost me to send something that weights 80 kg, has 3 cf and is no laptop."* And he will probably expect you not to send it as a Carton if a Heavy Carton would be cheaper.

So you take this input (and any other relevant input like distance) and check all rows that fulfill the condition with something like

```
select (your price formula depending on input) as cost
...
where (max_kg is null or max_kg >= 80) 
  and (max_cf is null or max_cf >= 3)
  and (is_laptop is null or is_laptop = 0)
order by cost
```

You should probably define that in a single place, so it's easier to add additional conditions (e.g. distince) and other specifications not defined in your table (e.g. rounding to full `cf` or steps of 0.1).

You will probably also need a table with additional services like express or overnight delivery, insurance for packages above 500$, delivery at a fixed time or similar.

You mentioned subcategories and "polymorphic price table", but it's not clear what you want to do with it. If you have some concrete examples that cannot be formulated in a matrix table like that, add them. But you should also be aware that simplicity is king, both for you and the customer. You would probably already lose me if I think you charge me `240$` for my `10kg/2.99cf` Carton if your competition does it for `200$`, even if you would actually just charge me `180$` for a Heavy Carton.

Comment: ...but then again, the express service would probably be cheaper than the regular service at this shop